# Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 and Typescript with jQuery DefinitelyTyped results in compilation errors

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, definitelytyped

I am investigating TypeScript and have run into a problem that others have also reported, but none of the answers I've seen seem particularly satisfactory.

The problem is that, having added jQuery.d.ts (using Nuget jQuery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped v2.8.8) to the Project results in multiple compiler errors.  Over 100 in fact.

My understanding is that for Visual Studio pre-Update 2, TypeScript had to be added as an extension.  However, since Update 2, TypeScript is included by default.

However, I note from the Visual Studio Extensions And Updates, that "TypeScript 1.7.5 for Visual Studio" is available.  Do I need to install this if I have Update 5 for VS2013?

From the Visual Studio Command Prompt, running "tsc.exe -v" gives me: 1.0.3.0.  (I think that this is the compiler version and not the version of TypeScript.)

Notes:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript shows me just one folder, "1.0"
- Some posts suggest updating the value in the PROJ file 1.0 from 1.0 to a higher value.

So, what steps to I need to take to get rid of these errors reported in the jQuery.d.ts file?

Many thanks

Griff

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled the DefinitelyTyped package, then installed TypeScript 1.7.5 and it fixed the problem for me.  After restarting VS, it asked me if I wanted to update the project to the newer version.  Reinstalled the DefinitelyTyped package again, and no errors.